# Correct way to diagnose mutex-related bottlenecks

Tags: c++, profiling, mutex

I'm working on an application in which a shared data structure (an `std::map`) is both read from and updated by multiple threads. The number of elements in the map is fixed at initialization, so the values frequently change but the keys do not. I use a mutex and a scoped lock, both provided by the Boost, to protect the access:

```
std::map<Key,Value> dataMap;
boost::mutex m;

void Set(Key k, Value v) {
  boost::scoped_lock sl(m);
  dataMap[k] = Value;
}

Value Get(Key k) {
  boost::scoped_lock sl(m);
  return dataMap[k];
}
```

How would I determine if access to the map is a bottleneck? It seems logical to me to time how long it takes to acquire the mutex in each case, e.g.

```
void Set(Key k, Value v) {
  Timer t; t.Start();
  boost::scoped_lock sl(m);
  t.Stop();
  cout << "Time taken to acquire mutex: " << t.Elapsed() << endl;
  dataMap[k] = Value;
}
```

I expect that, when there is low contention, the average time taken should be low, and as the contention increases (e.g. when there is a large number of threads), the average time taken will greatly increase.

Is this a valid way of diagnosing whether the access to the mutex is a bottleneck?

If not, are there any open-source programs that perform similar functionality correctly?

Comment: Gprof usually works well for me for profiling and showing me what function is taking the longest. I haven't used many others to compare though. So someone else could have a better opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what to use for your small test, but if you're program grows then I can recommend Intel Inspector Threading Error Analysis, it's not free but we've found it definitely worth it. It has a 30-day free trial that you could download to run some std::map tests on I guess.

http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-inspector-xe